# Laravel 8 "not required" validation rule

Tags: laravel

how can I "tell" laravel that if the email field with validation rule 'email' and URL field (for example field where I expect the user to put his Facebook account link but that field IS NOT required) with validation rule 'URL' is not required and it is fine if it is empty. I have put nullable() on all database table columns but my validation rule still applies like it is required. Here are the parts of the code.

This is from **migration**:

```
        $table->string('site_facebook')->nullable();
        $table->string('site_instagram')->nullable();
        $table->string('site_twitter')->nullable();
        $table->string('site_linkedin')->nullable();
        $table->string('site_behance')->nullable();
        $table->string('site_dribbble')->nullable();
        $table->string('site_email')->nullable();
```

This part is from **validation**:

```
        'site_facebook' => 'url',
        'site_facebook' => 'url',
        'site_instagram' => 'url',
        'site_twitter' => 'url',
        'site_linkedin' => 'url',
        'site_behance' => 'url',
        'site_dribbble' => 'url',
        'site_email' => 'email',
```

So, to wrap up my question. I want my URL and email fields to be optional not required :)

**EDIT**

Since there are some answers and no one work for me I just want to mention (if it does do anything with it), all of my validation rules are in a separate request...

```
    class ManageSiteSettingsRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'site_name' => 'required|max:50',
        'site_facebook' => 'nullable|url',
        'site_facebook' => 'url',
        'site_instagram' => 'url',
        'site_twitter' => 'url',
        'site_linkedin' => 'url',
        'site_behance' => 'url',
        'site_dribbble' => 'url',
        'site_email' => 'email',
        'site_creator_link' => 'url',
    ];
}
}
```

This is the form:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
```

@section('content')

```
<h2>Site settings</h2>

@include('includes._errors')
@include('includes._sessions')

<form action="{{ route('settings.update') }}" method="post">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_name">Site name</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_name" class="form-control" required placeholder="This field is required!" value="{{ $settings->site_name }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_description">Site description</label>
        <textarea name="site_description" class="form-control mytinytext" id="site_description" cols="30" rows="10">{!! $settings->site_description !!}</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_facebook">Site facebook page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_facebook" class="form-control" placeholder="https://www.facebook.com/" value="{{ $settings->site_facebook }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_instagram">Site instagram page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_instagram" class="form-control" placeholder="https://www.instagram.com/" value="{{ $settings->instagram }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_twitter">Site twitter page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_twitter" class="form-control" placeholder="https://twitter.com/" value="{{ $settings->site_twitter }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_linkedin">Site linkedin page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_linkedin" class="form-control" placeholder="https://www.linkedin.com/" value="{{ $settings->site_linkedin }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_behance">Site behance page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_behance" class="form-control" placeholder="https://www.behance.net/" value="{{ $settings->site_behance }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_dribbble">Site dribbble page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_dribbble" class="form-control" placeholder="https://dribbble.com/" value="{{ $settings->site_dribbble }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_email">Site email</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_email" class="form-control" placeholder="...@outlook... / ...@hotmail... / ...@gmail..." value="{{ $settings->site_email }}">
    </div>

    <hr class="divider">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_one">First footer field title</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_field_one" class="form-control" placeholder="PHONE" value="{{ $settings->site_field_one }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_one_value">First footer field value</label>
        <textarea name="site_field_one_value" id="site_field_one_value" class="mytinytext form-control" placeholder="+80 (0)5 22 55 66 77">{{ $settings->site_field_one_value }}</textarea>
    </div>

    <hr class="divider">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_two">Second footer field title</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_field_two" class="form-control" placeholder="ADDRESS" value="{{ $settings->site_field_two }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_two_value">Second footer field value</label>
        <textarea name="site_field_two_value" id="site_field_two_value" class="mytinytext form-control" placeholder="33 rue Burdeau 69089, Paris France">{{ $settings->site_field_two_value }}</textarea>
    </div>

    <hr class="divider">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_three">Third footer field title</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_field_three" class="form-control" placeholder="ENQUIRUES" value="{{ $settings->site_field_three }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_three_value">Third footer field value</label>
        <textarea name="site_field_three_value" id="site_field_three_value" class="mytinytext form-control" placeholder="email@gmail.com">{{ $settings->site_field_three_value }}</textarea>
    </div>

    <hr class="divider">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_four">Fourth footer field title</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_field_four" class="form-control" placeholder="WORK HOURS" value="{{ $settings->site_field_four }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_field_four_value">Fourth footer field value</label>
        <textarea name="site_field_four_value" id="site_field_four_value" class="mytinytext form-control" placeholder="Weekdays: 09:00 - 18:00  Weekends: 11:00 - 17:00">{{ $settings->site_field_four_value }}</textarea>
    </div>

    <hr class="divider">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_copyright">Site copyright</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_copyright" class="form-control" placeholder="Created with love by _______ (fill 'Site creator name' field)" value="{{ $settings->site_copyright }}">
    </div>

    <hr class="divider">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_creator_name">Site creator name</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_creator_name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe" value="{{ $settings->site_creator_name }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="site_creator_link">Site creator page</label>
        <input type="text" name="site_creator_link" class="form-control" placeholder="https://site-creator-page.com" value="{{ $settings->site_creator_link }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="btn_update_site_settings" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Update site settings</button>
    </div>
</form>

@include('includes._errors')
```

@endsection

Comment: use `sometimes` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: @KamleshPaul it does not work for me :3 When fields are empty it still do the validation

Comment: On the comment by @KamleshPaul and for anyone looking for the difference between `sometimes` and `nullable` validation rules... `sometimes` is for cases where the field will not be present in the `POST data` (generally `Request` object). In cases where the field exists but is empty, the validation will fail if another rule exists for the field. That's when the `nullable` rule advised in the accepted solution comes to the rescue. However, note that your DB column must be set to `NULL` by default (this is applicable at least for MySQL, MariaDB and Postgresql).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nullable rule

Like the example below:

```
'site_facebook' => 'url|nullable',
```

Comment: Did you try add nullable on your validation array ?

Comment: Yes, I added it on site_facebook => url|nullable and then went to submit the form to check will it still get validated and it does (I got error check and it displayed this message "The site facebook format is invalid." )

Comment: can you share with us the code of your form ?

Comment: I will add it to question

Comment: You have the rule in there twice, and the second one isn't nullable. This is the correct answer.